# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSMTPEmail

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5

Имеется Qt5.6 Ubuntu 16.04x64, исходники [v1.1](https://github.com/bluetiger9/SmtpClient-for-Qt)

Поправил *.pro

```
# Location of SMTP Library
SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION = $$PWD/../../../build/build-SMTPEmail-5_6-Debug
```

Добавил libSMTPEmail.so в /usr/lib
Попытка сборки:

```
g++ -m64 -o demo2 demo2.o sendemail.o moc_sendemail.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -L/media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/SmtpClient-for-Qt-1.1/demos/demo2/../../../build/build-SMTPEmail-5_6-Debug -lSMTPEmail -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSMTPEmail
Makefile:169: recipe for target 'demo2' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

cd /media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/build-SMTPEmail-5_6-Debug
# ls | grep libSMTPEmail.so
libSMTPEmail.so
libSMTPEmail.so.1
libSMTPEmail.so.1.0
libSMTPEmail.so.1.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стоит проверить одинаковые ли пути *"/media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/SmtpClient-for-Qt-1.1/demos/demo2/../../../build/build-SMTPEmail-5_6-Debug"* и *"/media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/build-SMTPEmail-5_6-Debug"*. Это не очевидно. Лучше положить для теста в явную директорию и прописать путь до неё.

Ну и после того как положил либы в /usr/lib неплохо было бы линковщику об этом рассказать:

```
   sudo ldconfig /usr/lib/
```

Comment: добавил: SMTP_LIBRARY_LOCATION = $$/media/bigdata/home/alexandr1/Qt/program/progQT/build-SMTPEmail-5_6-Debug